# Change video size from URL?

Tags: php, function, url, height, width

Helou :)

I have this following code

```
<?php
$koncovka = $_GET["url"];
$url_parsovani = "http://www.streamuj.tv/video/$koncovka";
$width = "640";
$height = "360";
```

Once I get on the video URL for example http://video.24tv.cz/index.php?url=6697adb1d9a00acde7a3 it gives me the preset width and height of the video.

Can you help me to transfer code, so I can change the video size from URL?
For example I would like to use this URL to set the video size to 960x540

`http://video.24tv.cz/index.php?url=6697adb1d9a00acde7a3?remote=1&width=960&height=540`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$width = "640";
$height = "360";
```

To the parameters read from the url (don't forget to validate the input).

```
$width = isset($_GET['width']) && is_numeric($_GET['width']) ? $_GET['width'] : '360';

$height = isset($_GET['height']) && is_numeric($_GET['height']) ? $_GET['height'] : '640';
```

It checks if there is a GET parameter passed and if it's of numeric type, otherwise is sets to a default value.

Comment: can you please help me one more time?

Comment: I have this following problem

Comment: After I enter the wrong URL on my site it shows me some errors and empty video player. **example here:** http://video.24tv.cz/index.php?url=1a660a85e9a2d02e976

If the url is right it shows only the video player and starts to play video correctly without errors, **example here:** http://video.24tv.cz/index.php?url=6697adb1d9a00acde7a3

Is there any way to change the code in index.php to redirect the user to 404 page after user enters the wrong url (the url without any video) ?

External php file [index.php][1]


  [1]: http://younews.sk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/index.txt

Comment: file returns false it it fails to load so just the first $rows = file($url) could be something like: if (!$rows = file($url)) { redirectTo404();}

Comment: and is it able to redirect it to some url? redirect to url how would you define that?